# Can you pass stage variables to a lambda using the proxy integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I can use stage variables to execute different lamdbas but it looks like you can also have mapping templates read them and do stuff based on their valued: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html

But Im using the lambda proxy integration so i dont have mapping templates. Is there a way to pass stage configuration variables to a lambda with the rpoxy integration?

Right now Im just doing this to use a stage variable to point to the right lambda for the stage: `Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${!stageVariables.LambdaFunctionName}/invocations`

Answer (score 4):

All the defined stage variables are passed in the `stageVariables` field of the `event` parameter in the lambda function:

```
import json
def handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(event['stageVariables'])
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't happen in Node.js

Comment: @Stephen, I've defined Stage Variables in API Gateway, but the event parameter of the Lambda function doesn't have them.  What do I need to do to pass the variables?

Comment: @AmosLong It should be passed from the gateway - I just implemented my Lambda in Python 3.7 (but it should be similar in JS) and used `event.get('stageVariables').get('env')` to retrieve value of `env` variable